# C++ - how format const char * using va_list and automatically manage internal buffers

Tags: c++, text, format, const-char

I use the standard `vsnprintf()` function for text formatting. It works well, but I must delete the buffer out of the function scope. I don't want to do it. I want to auto manage it. And I want to return `const char*`.

First, I thought that I can simply use a static `buffer`. But then I have a problem that I can't save multiple `format()` results and join them at the end, because the `buffer` is overwritten.

So, I wrote the function with a `const char*` pool. It has a limit of 1024 buffers, which is enough for my purposes, but I feel that this is not a good way to go.

Any idea how to deal with this issue?

Here is the original function:

```
const char * format(const char* fmt, ...)
{
    va_list vl;

    va_start(vl, fmt);
    int size = vsnprintf(0, 0, fmt, vl) + sizeof('\0');
    va_end(vl);

    char *buffer = new char [size];

    va_start(vl, fmt);
    size = vsnprintf(buffer, size, fmt, vl);
    va_end(vl);

    return buffer;
}
```

In some situations, I do several `format()` operations, so I need to save the result and merge it at the end. So, I rewrote the function to use the pool:

```
const char * format3(const char* fmt, ...) {
    static char **pool = new char *[1024]();
    static int sizes[1024];
    static int index = 0;
    static bool firstLoop = true;

    va_list vl;

    va_start(vl, fmt);
    int size = vsnprintf(0, 0, fmt, vl) + sizeof('\0');
    va_end(vl);

    char *buffer;

    if (firstLoop) {
        buffer = new char [size];
        pool[index] = buffer;
    } else {
        buffer = pool[index];
        int s = sizes[index];
        if (s < size) {
            delete [] buffer;
            buffer = new char [size];
            pool[index] = buffer;
        }
    }

    va_start(vl, fmt);
    size = vsnprintf(buffer, size, fmt, vl);
    va_end(vl);

    index++;
    if (index == 1024) {
        index = 0;
        firstLoop = false;
    }

    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: so just use `std::string`?

Comment: In worst case. I must rewrote a lot of code in this case.

Comment: Just don't use vararg functions in C++, that's my advice. If your compiler is new enough use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format), else use [the format library](https://fmt.dev/latest/index.html) that `std::format` is based on.

Comment: Thank you, I got work fmt lib. I will go into rewrite

Comment: va_args should have no place in C++ code.  Neither is char **pool. Where have you been learning C++ from, this looks more like "C". As said use more modern C++ and standard library support, there are much better ways of doing this.

Comment: Whether you switch to `std::format()` or equivalent, at the very least your `format()` should return `std::string` instead of `const char*`. That way, the memory is managed for you, and you get mess-free string concatenations for free. If you need to pass along the result of `format()` to some other function that needs a `const char*`, that is what `std::string::c_str()` is meant for. Also, do consider using a C++-style variadic template pack instead of using C-stye variadic parameters.

Comment: Thank you. I work on emulator written in C. However I slowly rewrite it to c++.

Comment: Returning `std::string` as recommended by @RemyLebeau is dangerous, because a call of the form `func (format4 ("%d", i).c_str());`, which is intended to pass a pointer to the output string to some other function may result in the returned instance of `std::string` being destructed before `func(...)` is called, and consequently leave the pointer returned by `c_str()` pointing to de-allocated memory.  Not all compilers do this, but I can bear personal witness to one that actually did.

Comment: I notice that `sizes[...]` is used but not set.

Comment: @Jonno "*I can bear personal witness to one that actually did*" - then that compiler was broken, because the C++ standard guarantees the lifetime of temporary objects until the end of the *whole* expression that creates them. In a *conforming* compiler, `func (format4 ("%d", i).c_str())` would be perfectly safe, the temp `std::string` would not be destroyed until *after* `func()` returns. The only thing that *would* be unsafe is if `func()` saved the pointer somewhere for later use. THAT would be a dangling pointer in this case, but that is a separate issue.

Answer (score 0):

> how to deal with this issue?

In C, you *do not* deal with the issue. In C, I would *expect* users to *want* to deallocate memory themselves, it is completely normal. In C, do not hide deallocation, let the users now what they are doing.

In C++, there are the whole object lifetime and object destructors are executed at the end of variable scope. In C++, use `std::string`, which exists to manage string memory and will deallocate strings automatically.

Overall, in C++, there are sstreams, in particular `std::stringstream` and in newer C++ there is `std::format`. You would typically prefer them in C++.

> ```
> + sizeof('\0');
> ```

`sizeof('\0')` sounds confusing, it is 4 in C and 1 in C++. Just `+ 1`. When you are dealing with C strings, it is typical that your code is sprinkled with `+ 1` everywhere.